# CastException in Nio server : SocketChannelImpl cannot be cast to ServerSocketChannel

Tags: java, nio, classcastexception

i use pseudo code to describe the problem first,and i'll paste the whole code in the follow,which can run in the local.

```
1.selector = Selector.open();
  serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
  serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
  serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port), 1024);
  serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

2.while(true){
   selector.select();
   Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
   Iterator<SelectionKey> it = keys.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
     SelectionKey key = it.next();
3.   if(!key.isAcceptable()){
        continue;
     }
4.   ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
     ...
    }
  }
```

the exception occured in the step 4,then i do a check in the step 3,but it can not pass the acceptable check and go into a dead loop.
occasionally ,it can receive and response normally and i have not make any change,it's too strange to me.
here i paste the code and hope someone can help me. thanks.

```html
package io.Nio;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import io.util.IOUtil;

public class NioServer extends Thread{

 private int port;

 private Selector selector;

 private ServerSocketChannel serverChannel;

 public NioServer(int port){
  this.port = port;
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
  try{
   selector = Selector.open();
   serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
   serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
   serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port), 1024);
   serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
  }catch(IOException e){
   IOUtil.close(serverChannel);
  }

  System.out.println("server start:" + port); 
  while(true){
   try {
    selector.select();
   } catch (ClosedSelectorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
   Iterator<SelectionKey> it = keys.iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
    SelectionKey key = it.next();
    if(!key.isValid()){
     key.cancel();
     IOUtil.close(key.channel());
     IOUtil.close(key.selector());
     System.out.println(IOUtil.now() + "clear a invalid key."); 
     continue;
    }
    
    // i put a check here,if is not Acceptable,then continue, but it's a dead loop
    if(!key.isAcceptable()){
     System.out.println("not Acceptable");
     continue;
    }

    try {
     //Exception here: SocketChannelImpl cannot be cast to ServerSocketChannel
     ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
     SocketChannel channel = serverChannel.accept();
     if(channel == null){
      continue;
     }

     channel.configureBlocking(false);
     channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
     
//     if (key.isReadable()){
//      System.out.println("not read");
//     }

     ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
     if (channel.read(buffer) > 0) {
      buffer.flip();
      byte[] byteArray = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
      buffer.get(byteArray);
      String expression = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
      System.out.println(IOUtil.now() + "receive request：" + expression);
      String result = null;
      response(channel, result);
     }
    }catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }

 }

 public void shutdown(){
  IOUtil.close(selector);
  IOUtil.close(serverChannel); 
 }

 private void response(SocketChannel channel, String response) throws IOException {
  response = "hello response";
  System.out.println(IOUtil.now() + "send response："+ response);
  byte[] bytes = response.getBytes();
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes.length);
  buffer.put(bytes);
  buffer.flip();
  channel.write(buffer);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new NioServer(IOUtil.DEFAULT_PORT).start();
 }
}
```

```html
package io.Nio;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import io.util.IOUtil;

public class NioClient extends Thread{

 private volatile CountDownLatch connectLatch; 

 private String ip;

 private int port;

 private Selector selector;  

 private SocketChannel socketChannel;


 private NioClient(String ip, int port) { 
  this.ip = ip;
  this.port = port;
  connectLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
 }

 public static NioClient open(String ip, int port){
  NioClient client = new NioClient(ip,port);
  client.start();
  return client;
 }

 @Override
 public void run(){  
  try{
   long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
   System.out.println(IOUtil.now() + "start client");
   selector = Selector.open(); 
   socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(); 
   socketChannel.configureBlocking(false); 
   socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip,port));
   while(!socketChannel.finishConnect()){
    yield();
   }
   System.out.println(IOUtil.now() + "cost time：" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - begin) + "ms"); 
   connectLatch.countDown();
   socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
   while(true){
    selector.select(); 
    Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();  
    while(it.hasNext()){  
     SelectionKey key = it.next();
     if(!key.isValid() || !key.isReadable()){ 
      continue;
     }

     SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();  
     ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024); 
     if(channel.read(buffer) > 0){
      buffer.flip(); 
      byte[] byteArray = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
      buffer.get(byteArray);
      String response = new String(byteArray,"UTF-8");  
      System.out.println(IOUtil.now() + "receive response：" + response);  
     }
    }  
   }
  }catch(IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 } 
 
 public void request(String request) { 
  try {
   connectLatch.await();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   System.out.println(IOUtil.now() + "interrupted" + e.getMessage());
  }
  try {
   byte[] bytes = request.getBytes();  
   ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes.length);  
   buffer.put(bytes); 
   buffer.flip();  
   socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
   //TODO
   System.out.println(IOUtil.now() + "send request：" + request);
   socketChannel.write(buffer); 
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }  
 }  

 public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  NioClient client = NioClient.open(IOUtil.DEFAULT_HOST, IOUtil.DEFAULT_PORT);
  client.request("hello");
//  while(true){
//   sleep(500); 
//   String request = IOUtil.buileRequest(1991);
//   client.request(request);
//  }
 }
}
```

```html
package io.util;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class IOUtil {

 public static final String DEFAULT_HOST = "127.0.0.1";

 public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;

 public static final String operators[] = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};

 public static final int CLIENNT_NUM = 10;

 public static final boolean CLIENT_CLOSEABLE = true;
 
 public static String now(){
  return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss SSS ").format(new Date());
 }
 
 public static String buileRequest(int seed){
  Random random = new Random(seed);
  return random.nextInt(10) + IOUtil.operators[random.nextInt(4)] + (random.nextInt(10) + 1);
 }

 public static void close(Closeable io) {
  if (io != null) {
   try {
    io.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: Never seen this. You don't need to close the selector just because a key is invalid, and if it is invalid it is already cancelled, so you don't need to cancel it, and anyway closing the channel cancels the key. Very strange code here. Why aren't you interested in OP_READ on the channels you have accepted and registered for OP_READ? And why are you trying to read from a channel you have just accepted, without waiting for OP_READ? And why are you printing "not read" when you are about to read from the channel? I suggest you have a good look at the NIO Tutorial. This code is rubbish.

Comment: You are also calling `key.isReadable()` on the wrong key.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Clearly this is not the real code.

Comment: sorry,my mistake. i've midify it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way the exception you describe could occur is if you attempt that typecast on a channel which is not a `ServerSocketChannel`, which could happen if its key is ready but not 'acceptable'. Clearly you didn't have your step 2 when you got this exception, so you processed a 'readable' channel as though it was an 'acceptable' channel.

So the code you posted doesn't actually exhibit that problem, but it does have a large number of others. You don't need to close the selector just because a key is invalid, and if it is invalid it is already cancelled, so you don't need to cancel it, and anyway closing the channel cancels the key. Why aren't you interested in OP_READ/`isReadable()` on the channels you have accepted and registered for OP_READ? And why are you trying to read from a channel you have just accepted, without waiting for OP_READ?

Throw it away and have a good look at the Java NIO tutorial.

I do want to comment on one particular piece of nonsense in the client:

```
socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(); 
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false); 
socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip,port));
while(!socketChannel.finishConnect()){
    yield();
}
```

Here you are performing the equivalent of a blocking-mode connect in non-blocking mode. It can all be replaced by:

```
socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(); 
socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip,port));
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
```

Then:

```
socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
```

Here you are registering for an event *that has already happened*. Truly bizarre. You will never get OP_CONNECT from an already-connected socket. Remove.